# xml multiple namespaces in root

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I am having trouble generating an xml root.  I have to match this structure as the elements of the xml use the prefixs throughout.

```
<ShipmentReceiptNotification
xmlns="urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02"
xmlns:dacc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03"
xmlns:dbpq="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:BookPriceQualifier:xsd:codelist:01.04"
xmlns:dccc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:CreditCardClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03"
xmlns:dcrt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:CustomerType:xsd:codelist:01.03"
..\..\XML\Interchange\ShipmentReceiptNotification_02_02.xsd">
```

if I do something like

```
XmlNode ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ShipmentReceiptNotification", "xmlns=\"urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02\"xmlns:dacc=\"urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03\"");
```

I get

> -ShipmentReceiptNotification
>   xmlns="xmlns="urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02"xmlns:dacc=&
>
> quot;urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03"">

Comment: The namespace is the part after `xmlns="`. It's just `urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02`, for instance. Also, don't worry about putting them all in the root. Just create the correct elements and attributes, in the correct namespaces. Also, you'll find LINQ to XML much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `CreateElement` accepts the URI of the namespace that the *element being created*, that is `ShipmentReceiptNotification`, belongs to. Not the whole bunch of `xmlns` attributes. This code:

```
XmlElement e = xmlDoc.CreateElement(
    "ShipmentReceiptNotification",
    "urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02");
```

Produces this XML:

```
<ShipmentReceiptNotification 
    xmlns="urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02" />
```

To produce what you want, you need to *add attributes* to the element. Like this:

```
XmlElement e = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ShipmentReceiptNotification");
e.SetAttribute("xmlns", "urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02");
e.SetAttribute("xmlns:dacc", "urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03");
```

Produces this XML:

```
<ShipmentReceiptNotification 
    xmlns="urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02" 
    xmlns:dacc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03" />
```

Note that this is the “manual” way. You should play with [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) to do it “right”. However, that may be a bit more complex task which need not be necessary for your scenario.

Comment: I believe I need to use the xmlnamespacemanager as I can add all the attributes but when I create elements with prefixs the prefix as defined in the attributes will not display in the ending xmldocument.

Comment: Yes. Just don't be surprised that `XmlDocument` won't accept any `XmlNamespaceManager` instance anywhere; they both just share the same `XmlNameTable` instance.

Comment: do I have to use xelement ?

Comment: In the latest versions of .NET there are two parallel XML libraries: `XmlDocument` et al. and `XDocument` et al. The later being more recent, and LINQ-enabled. Which one to use depends on your use case and also on the mere fact if you already have a substantial amount of code utilizing one or another.

Comment: I would prefer to stick to xmldocument but I can't get any prefixs for later elements to work with the attribute method for root node namespaces